# Generic Parameter Requires type "Nothing" when T is type "Any"

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I am a new Kotlin programmer, and I am having a problem relating to generics

In the following code, I am getting an error with `it.get(this)` "Type mismatch.
Required: Nothing. Found: Any.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Any.getPropertiesWithType() =
    this::class.memberProperties
        .filter { it.returnType.isSubtypeOf(T::class.starProjectedType) }
        .map {
            it.isAccessible = true
            it.get(this) as T
        }
```

This is confusing because `memberProperties` returns a `Collection<KProperty1<T, *>>` where T is the type of `this`, which is `Any` in my case. `KProperty1.get()` takes one argument of that same type T, so I would expect `Any` could be passed without an issue.

One thing I noticed is that `it` in the filter and map are both type `KProperty<out Any, *>>` but `memberProperties` does not have the out variance.

If I replace `this::class` with `this.javaClass.kotlin`, it works without an error, but that seems like a very bad way to go about this.

If anyone knows a way to fix this, or an entirely different strategy, it would be much appreciated. I am new to Kotlin and still do things in the Java way sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this::class` is analogous to `this.getClass()` in Java, which returns a `KClass<out Any>` (`Class<? extends Object>` in Java). After all, just because the type of `this` is `Any`, its runtime type may not be `Any` - it could be any subclass of `Any`. `out Any` captures this idea.

Therefore, the `memberProperties` of `this::class` will be a collection of `KProperty1<out Any, *>`.

In the same way that you cannot add anything to a `MutableList<out Any>` using `add`, you cannot `get` the value of a `KProperty1<out Any, *>` - an input parameter's type is marked `out`. Another way to think about this is that the property could be on any subclass of `Any`, trying to get the property using `this`, which is just an `Any`, obviously doesn't work.

I would move the unchecked cast to `it`:

```
(it as KProperty1<Any, T>).get(this)
```

As for why `.javaClass` works, it is because `javaClass` actually gives you a `Class<Any>`, not `Class<out Any>`. IMO, this doesn't make much sense, but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I wanted to avoid an unchecked cast, but I guess it's really the only option here.

Comment: @bush You *could* do this without unchecked casts if you did `this.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties...`, but 1. that just feels less readable 2. there is actually a hidden unchecked cast in `javaClass`. How else could it be implemented to return a `Class<Any>` other than using an unchecked cast? :D 3. IMO, unchecked casts in reflection code like this is expected to a degree. I don't think you should worry about getting rid of every one of them.